# Как начать отсчёт слайдов с единицы?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, swiper

Делаю свою пагинацию для слайдера свайпера. Когда использую шаблонную строку для того, чтобы вернуть `span` с номером слайдера, он начинает отсчёт с нуля.

Как сделать так, чтобы отсчёт слайдов начинался с единицы?

```js
const slider = new Swiper('.hero__swiper', {

  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'bullets',
    renderBullet: function (index, className) {
      return (
        `<span class=${className}>${'0' + index}</span>`
        );

    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном кусочке кода нужно прибавлять 1 к индексу.

```
 `<span class=${className}>${'0' + (index + 1) }</span>`
```

На всякий случай я поставил проверку если index больше  9:

```
const slider = new Swiper('.hero__swiper', {

  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'bullets',
    renderBullet: function (index, className) {
      const paginationNum = index < 9 ? '0' + (index + 1) : index + 1;
      return (
        `<span class=${className}>${paginationNum}</span>`
        );

    },
  },
})
```